# Transform list of dict (with 2 keys/values) in a single dict where values of first key is the key of the second value

Tags: python, django, dictionary, group-by

I want to make aggregations and use annotate with Count (group by).
But I would like to transform my result as below

```
mygroupby = Mymodel.objects.all().values('field1').annotate(total=Count('field1'))
result = [wound_stat for wound_stat in wound_stats]
```

**currently result**

```
[
    {'field1': 'A', 'total': 1}, 
    {'field1': 'B', 'total': 4}, 
    {'field1': 'C', 'total': 2}, 
    {'field1': 'D', 'total': 2}, 
    {'field1': 'E', 'total': 2}
]
```

**expected result**

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 2, 'D': 2, 'E': 2}
```

what is the best way?
regards

Comment: `{mapping['field1']: mapping['total'] for mapping in result}` or `dict(map(operator.itemgetter('field1', 'total'), result))`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `values_list` to get list of tuples:

```
mygroupby = Mymodel.objects.all().annotate(total=Count('field1')).values_list('field1', "total")
```

and do final transformation in python:

```
result = {i[0]:i[1] for i in mygroupby}
```

it's probably suboptimal, but simple enough to figure out what's happening